# How to configure TinySort to put elements without an attribute last?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, tinysort

I can't make TinySort put elements with a missing attribute below the sorted elements. Options like "place" and "emptyEnd" don't change the order at all.

Please take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/dm8cz4ra/1/

If I pick only the elements with the attribute using `nodeList = $('#list > div[position]')` they always land at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working, but you need to inform TinySort that a position is existing. So instead of:

```
<div id="list">
  <div position="0">0</div>
  <div position="-1">-1</div>
  <div position="1">1</div>
  <div>NULL</div>
</div>
```

Use

```
<div id="list">
  <div position="0">0</div>
  <div position="-1">-1</div>
  <div position="1">1</div>
  <div position="">NULL</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dm8cz4ra/14/)